# PHP SoapClient, I just cannot get it to work

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to learn how to access soap web services via PHP. I can get a list of functions available. I cannot get a return from a SoapClient function. My code is as follows:

```
    <?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
    $fcs = 'fcs is initialized';
    $url = 'url is initialized';
    $res = 'res is initialized';
    $url = 'http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL';
    $param = array('ZIP' => '72685');
    try {
        $client = new SoapClient($url);
        $fcs = $client->__getFunctions();
        $res = $client->GetCityForecastByZIP($param);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<h2>Exception Error!</h2>";
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo '<br> url = '.$url;
    echo '<br> fcs = '.$fcs;
    echo '<br> res = '.$res.'<br>';
    ?>
```

I have tried about 6 Soap testing URLs that google can find. Some (http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl) of them have evolved into something else. The one I tried the most (http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL) did seem to be having the same trouble I was in it's web page implementation, http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx.

the Exception Error! is

> "Server was unable to process request. ---> A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server."

To repeat my results,

1) the Soap client object creation seems to work w/o error.

2) __getFunctions seems to work w/o error.

3) trying to get a result from any of the functions produces the error shown above.

**Questions:**

1) Is there any error in my code that would cause it not to work?

2) What is a good working Soap Web Service URL sandbox?

Comment: is that the error message returned by the remote server, in response to your request? Because it sounds like there is an error on that server where it cannot connect to a database. I'm not sure that's really the fault of your code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like its the weather service. To rule out your code go to `http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?op=GetCityWeatherByZIP`

Add your ZIP into the Zip box and hit 'Invoke' and you will get an SQL error. So I would say its safe to assume its not your code and its the server.